# Linux -How to delete all files in a directory without using find

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to delete all files in my directory "XYZ" without using find command in bash on Linux.

Comment: What about `rm /your/dir/*`? It will delete all files (no directories). With `rm -r /your/dir` you will delete everything.

Comment: when you asked a question, describe it clearly please. 1. if you want to **only** rm files, (excluding dir? link? ) 2. do you want to do deletion recursively?

Comment: be very careful when you use `rm -rf *` or any variation of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
rm -f XYZ/*
```

If you want to delete also subdirectories, use:

```
rm -fr XYZ/*
```

If you also want to delete the directory, use

```
rm -fr XYZ
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete all files in a directory, go into the directory and execute: **rm -f ***

Comment: Small detail: the above will not remove any files starting with '.'. For that, use a separate command: `rm -f .*`

Answer (score 1):

Why would `find` even enter into it? use `rm -r XYZ` to recursively remove the directory `XYZ`.